# Study the limit of a sequence defined recursively involving square root

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

**Problem**

> Consider $c>0$ and the sequence $(u_n)$ defined recursively by $u_1=1$ and
> $$
> u_{n+1}=\sqrt{u_n+c n} \quad n \ge 1.
>  $$
> Find an equivalent of $u_n$ of the form $u_n \sim \alpha n^\beta$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real numbers, and compute $$\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n-\alpha n^\beta$$.

Click [here](https://www.ip-paris.fr/sites/default/files/pages/documents/2020-09/maths_2016.pdf) for the source of the problem (page 5/9 of the PDF file). The original question assumes that $c$ is a non-negative real number but when $c=0$ the problem is trivial.

**My Question**

Is my attempt below valid and getting to the right place (except setting $\beta=\frac{1}{2}$ directly)? The biggest problem is that I only *find* $\alpha$ but $\beta$ is out of a pure *guess* (although I believe it should be correct). If I am in the right direction, how can I give a valid discovery of such $\beta$? (I have no concrete clue but I believe there should be another equation around $\beta$ to be solved.)

**My attempt (with guess).**

I have been asked to show that there exists a real number $\sigma$ such that $u_n \le \sigma\sqrt{n}$ for all $n \ge 1$, and according to my computation, $\sigma$ exists as long as it satisfies

$$
\sigma \ge \frac{1+\sqrt{1+8c}}{4}.
$$

For the question above, I am thinking about using the relation

$$
u_{n+1}^2-u_n^2=u_n-u_{n-1}+c
$$

and replace $u_n$ with $\alpha n^\beta$ and solve it for $\alpha$ and $\beta$. According to the given relation $u_n \le \sigma \sqrt{n}$, I would guess $\beta=\frac{1}{2}$. Then the relation above gives, when $n$ is big enough,

$$
\alpha^2[(n+1)-n]=\alpha^2=\alpha(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1})+c \to c
$$

Hence we have $\alpha=\sqrt{c}$. As a result,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n \to \infty} u_{n+1}-\alpha (n+1)^\beta &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{u_n+cn}-\sqrt{c(n+1)} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{u_n+cn-c(n+1)}{\sqrt{u_n+cn}+\sqrt{c(n+1)}} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{u_n-c}{\sqrt{u_n+cn}+\sqrt{c(n+1)}} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{u_n}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt{\frac{u_n}{n}+c}+\sqrt{c\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{c}} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your question is how we guess the value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, here is the method.

First, it's easy to prove that $u_n \to +\infty$ (as $n_{n+1} > \sqrt{cn}$).

And you proved already that $\frac{u_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ is bounded. So, we must have $\beta \leq \frac{1}{2}<1$. Then $n^{\beta -1} \to 0$
.

From the question, we need to prove $u_n \sim \alpha n^{\beta}$, by knowning $u_{n+1} = \sqrt{u_n +cn}$, we have

$$
\begin{align}
& \alpha(n+1)^{\beta} \sim\sqrt{ \alpha n^{\beta} + cn} \\
&\Longleftrightarrow  \alpha n^{\beta}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\beta} \sim \sqrt{c} n^{\frac{1}{2}} \left(1+\frac{\alpha}{c} n^{\beta - 1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow  \alpha n^{\beta}\left(1+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\sim \sqrt{c} n^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(1+o\left(n^{\beta -1}\right)\right) \\
&\Longleftrightarrow  \alpha n^{\beta}  \sim \sqrt{c} n^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align} 
$$

So, we must havethat $(\alpha, \beta) =\left(\sqrt{c}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$.